# robocopy copying parent folders

Tags: powershell

I have a directory of photos that are placed in folders named with the date each photo is taken. I want to move all photos to another folder.

`robocopy 'source' 'target' *.jpg /s` copies the parent date folders as well. how to stop this from happening?

Comment: If you don't want it to copy parent folders, **don't use robocopy** there are many other commands for copying files, but `robocopy` copies **the full filepath**. Use `xcopy` or `copy` instead.

Comment: robocopy is a _directory oriented_ copier. it accepts a source, a destination ... and other optional parameters. it is designed for copying a _directory or directory tree and the content thereof_.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in native powershell:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\source -Filter *.jpg -Destination c:\target –Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

basically, to answer your question. its because of the /s parameter